# Use caption and long description for figure

Tags: floats, captions

I want to have to following text at my figures:

```
<< FIGURE >>
Figure 1: Title of my figure which is displayed in the list of figures
Here in a new line a long description about the figure, in a smaller text
```

I've found this one:

```
\caption[Title of my figure which is displayed...]%
  {Here in a new line a long...}
```

The problem with the given code is that I get not the title under my figure, only "Figure 1: Here in a new line a long...".

How to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: You got the syntax of `\caption` wrong. The correct form is: `\caption[<short caption using in the list-of-figures>]{<full caption which is displayed under the figure>}`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the `\caption` macro for the (short) "heading" of the figure and just add the longer description into the `figure` environment (after the `\caption` and with proper vertical spacing).

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{foo}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% Placeholder for actual figure
\caption{Title of my figure which is displayed in the list of figures}
\medskip
\small
Here in a new line a long description about the figure, in a smaller text
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The only problem for this is that the small text will be centred, and I prefer it justified. I used the package caption and I quite liked it.

Comment: @Vivi how did the `caption` package solve the problem of the small text being centred ?

Answer (score 12):

The solution is very simple and does not need any vertical adjustment (i.e., `\vspace`). Instead of

```
\caption[Short Title]%
{Long Description}
```

try:

```
\caption[Short Title]%
{Short Title \par \small Long Description}
```

Indeed, you only to repeat the title once in the `[]` and again at the beginning of `{}`. The title and description should be separated by `\par \small` (or any other font-size you prefer) to break the line and change the size. This will produce:

```
<< FIGURE >>
Figure 1: Short Title
Long Description (in a smaller font!)
```

while only keeps the **Short Title** in the list of figures.

I usually do not want a new line (I prefer to have the title and description as one paragraph). Therefore, I do:

```
\caption[Short Title]%
{Short Title- Long Description}
```

which produces:

```
<< FIGURE >>
Figure 1: Short Title- Long Description
```

Comment: When using this solution 'short title' just doesn't appear for me.

Comment: Have you repeated the *short title* twice?

Comment: @BorhanKazimipour Yeah, because the content of `[]` goes in the list of figures. And better create an own command that warps this around to ensure similar behaviour in all figures.

Comment: Thank you @OlegLobachev for the **wrapper** suggestion.

Comment: In my first comment, I asked if @par followed my suggestion and actually repeated the **short title** twice.

Answer (score 9):

Extension of answer by [Borhan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422496/77645) (not enough rep to comment so posting as a seperate answer):

Use `\newcommand` to avoid having to repeat every short title, and to add some decorations. For example, the following works very nicely:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}

\newcommand{\mycaption}[2]{\caption[#1]{\textbar\, \textbf{#1.} #2}}

...

\mycaption{Short Title}{Longer description.}
```

This shows the short title in the list of figures, and in the actual caption gives (**=in bold):

```
 << Figure >>
 *Figure 1 | Short Title.* Longer description.
```

You can easily edit the command to add a break after the short title, make the text smaller, change colors, etcetera.

Answer (score -2):

In addition to the comment above, you can have a look at the caption package which allows for many customizations.

http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption

Comment: -1 :( because it doesn't offer a solution. Can you please give an example how the problem could be solved with the `caption` package ?