# Standard Ways to Add Details After Captions?

Tags: captions

When it comes to `table`s/`figure`s, is it more common/standard/beneficial to put descriptions inside `caption`s? I have separated descriptions from captions as follows, but I saw [Use caption and long description for figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24496/use-caption-and-long-description-for-figure) recently.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is a sentence.

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{This is the title.}
\small The beginning description if needed.\par
{\centering\begin{tabular}{cccc} \hline
0.1234 & 0.5678 & 0.1234 & 0.5678 \\
0.1234 & 0.5678 & 0.1234 & 0.5678 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}\par}
The ending description if needed.
\end{table}

This is a sentence.

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{This is the title.}
\small The beginning description if needed.\par
{\centering\rule{2in}{1.5in}\par}
The ending description if needed.
\end{figure}

This is a sentence.

\end{document}
```

As I have been studying LaTeX with no textbook, I even wonder whether the `caption`s are in general located before/after the `table`s/`figure`s. What is the best practice for writing the titles and the descriptions? Thanks.

Comment: Usual convention: **(Tables)** Caption right *before* of the table. **(Figures)** Caption right *after* the figure. **(Recommendation)** Read a decent book about LaTeX :).

Comment: Some publications (IEEEtran) require using their own standard \caption (much to the dismay of many authors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usual convention:

- **(Tables)** Caption right *before* of the table. Reason is (afaik), that a table can potentially span more than one page.
- **(Figures)** Caption right *after* the figure.
- The captions can be multi line -- no problem.
- **(Recommendation)** Read a decent book about LaTeX :)

Additional information about the object (table or figure) is usually placed within the normal text and *not* within the environment (`table` or `figure`).

---

### Basic Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is a sentence.

\begin{table}
\centering % optional
\caption{This is the title.}
\label{tab:TableID}
% Code for generating table.
\end{table}

This is a sentence that may include information regarding \tablename~\ref{tab:TableID}.

\begin{figure}
\centering % optional
% Code for generating figure, like \includegraphics[]{}.
\caption{This is the title.}
\label{fig:FigureID}
\end{figure}

This is a sentence that may include information regarding \figurename~\ref{fig:FigureID}.

\end{document}
```

---

### More Advanced Example

Needs two LaTeX runs before the references are correct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

This is a sentence.

\begin{table}[H] % H option from float package.
\centering % optional
\caption{This is the title.}
\label{tab:TableID}
% Code for generating table.
\includegraphics[width = 0.8\textwidth]{example-image} % See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738
\end{table}

This is a sentence that may include information regarding \tablename~\ref{tab:TableID}.

\begin{figure}[H] % H option from float package.
\centering % optional
% Code for generating figure, like \includegraphics[]{}.
\includegraphics[width = 0.8\textwidth]{example-image} % See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738
\caption{This is the title.}
\label{fig:FigureID}
\end{figure}

This is a sentence that may include information regarding \figurename~\ref{fig:FigureID}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I understood well, the OP asked also where to put some description after the captions.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes, there are two questions, the one that you mentioned and one regarding the position of the caption. I reply two both, but one of the questions I answer not directly (--> don't do it) :). So far the OP did not comment within 14 hours at all as you can see. Therefore I do not know if my answer is ok.

Comment: My apologies for this delayed response. I asked this banal question because I realized that I have exploited LaTeX as if it is a WYSIWYG device instead of a markup language (that is, thinking output first and then writing code) as I get accustomed to it. Studying LaTeX, I thought that its grammar was structured deliberately, although I have been unavoidably abusing it producing spaghetti code to tailor documents rather than understanding the philosophy considerately. The reason of the different caption practices of tables and figures seems apparent, but why is separating information preferred?

Comment: @JunyongKim Please elaborate your question.